# Plotting images in different colors

Tags: matlab, colors

I have a gray scale image where I have marked the pixels from 1 - 16.

I want to visualize different intensity pixels in different shades of colors. What is the easiest way to do it such that these numbers 1-16 can be anything ( for eg 5,10,20 ).

I have looked at colormap but am unable to use it in this fashion.

Comment: you mean a different shade of grey? or a different color shade, like blue or red?

Comment: Why not to use colormap jet?

Comment: Different shade.... @Mercury - Could you let me know how to use it in this scenario ...

Comment: imagesc(img);colormap jet;